# Android не воспроизводит видео

Tags: android, videoview

Запускаю приложение на эмуляторе от `Genymotion`.

> Ошибка воспроизведения видео

Делаю так:

```
VideoView videoView = findViewById(R.id.videoView);
videoView.setVideoPath("android.resource://" + getPackageName()+  "/" + R.raw.demo);
videoView.start();
```

Comment: покажите лог ошибки

Comment: 03-10 12:26:02.633 1360-1360/com.example.usingvideo E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier
03-10 12:26:03.125 1360-1370/com.example.usingvideo E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
03-10 12:26:03.129 1360-1360/com.example.usingvideo E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: а без этих трех строк собирается и работает?

Comment: Да, ошибка как понимаю в пути файла.
Да и при копировании видео в папку raw, студия предлагает выбрать "формат", например      
java, text, js и т.д "формата" MP4 нет. 
Я ещё зеленый в андроид разработке, так что прошу понимания.